# How does ConcurrentReferenceHashMap work?

Tags: java, spring, concurrency, hashmap

We have a situation using spring-cloud-netflix-core library which is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47269164). I think the issue is with the way `CachingSpringLoadBalancerFactory` is using `ConcurrentReferenceHashMap` which is reported [here](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/2443).
And also from the documentation of `ConcurrentReferenceHashMap` (which uses soft references):

> The use of references means that there is no guarantee that items placed into the map will be subsequently available. The garbage collector may discard references at any time, so it may appear that an unknown thread is silently removing entries.

Now my questions are:
1. Is my understanding in the following correct?

```
// Original code is in CachingSpringLoadBalancerFactory in spring-cloud-netflix-core
// cache is a field of type ConcurrentReferenceHashMap
if (this.cache.containsKey(clientName)) {
  return this.cache.get(clientName); // This can be null, right?
}
```

2. Is there anyway to write a test case for it. We managed to reproduce it once in an standalone application with limited memory (`-Xmx50m`). But how can we write a unit test to cover such scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As to your question, yes, that's correct. Generally, this is a variation on `WeakHashMap`, as stated in the docs.

The JavaDoc for `WeakHashMap` says:

"The behavior of the `WeakHashMap` class depends in part upon the actions of the garbage collector, so several familiar (though not required) `Map` invariants do not hold for this class. Because the garbage collector may discard keys at any time, a `WeakHashMap` may behave as though an unknown thread is silently removing entries. In particular, even if you synchronize on a `WeakHashMap` instance and invoke none of its mutator methods, it is possible for the `size` method to return smaller values over time, for the `isEmpty` method to return `false` and then `true`, for the `containsKey` method to return `true` and later `false` for a given key, for the `get` method to return a value for a given key but later return `null`, for the `put` method to return `null` and the `remove` method to return `false` for a key that previously appeared to be in the map, and for successive examinations of the key set, the value collection, and the entry set to yield successively smaller numbers of elements."

Because of this behavior, it is quite difficult to test. You can use the `getReference()` method of the map and the `release()` method of the corresponding elements to simulate the purges if you want to test some invariants.

Answer (score 1):

It should depend on if your keys and values are strongly referenced outside of the map, by my understanding of the intent of the docs. You don't tell if that's the case or not.

However, the map implementation (up until now) doesn't appear to actually use soft/weak references to individual keys/values but to manage internal non-strongly-referenced map entries, which then depending on type of reference get nulled out on either gc (weak references) or low memory (soft references), disregarding strong reachability of keys/values. Workarounds until it gets fixed (or my bug report is invalidated ;-) ) would include using Hibernate/Hibernate validator's classes with the same name (Doug Lee's public domain implementation which somehow never got included into the JDK), or Guava's MapMaker.weakKeys().weakValues() in case you don't really need soft references.

See https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/24253

Comment: With Hibernate did you mean STRONG keys and WEAK values? So that once the value is removed its corresponding key is also removed?
As for WEAK keys - there is no way to retrieve a key, to make sure that it is not going to be deleted by GC